# How to debug my webcam problems?

Tags: macos, skype, webcam

I'm quite a new OS X user and come from a linux background - usually to debug my problems I consult the logs as per `/var/log/syslog` however with Yosemite i'm not sure what i'm looking for.

Any way my problem is that I will load Skype and video call someone which works fine but the moment my mac is locked or goes into hibernation mode the next time I try video call the web cam is not detected - if i attempt to use Photo Booth this too doesn't detect a webcam.  Some google searches has revealed it's a conflict where the camera is "in use" when it isn't - and other articles seem to point towards AirParrot which i do not have installed.

1. How would I determine where the fault is?
2. How do I then resolve this fault?

Rebooting does seem to be a solution but IMO theres a bug that needs fixing because rebooting to get a cam to work is just simply absurd - even Windows can function more reliably.

Comment: When this happens, open Terminal and run `sudo killall VDCAssistant`. I have an issue with my webcam as well where moving the screen will disconnect the camera... Killing `VDCAssistant` fixes my issue sometimes.

Comment: Legend - thanks for the quick reply works a charm.  I would never have known how to do this :P

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861186/825364

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented by @aglasser to fix the Cam not working simply:

- Open `Terminal.app`; and
- Run: `sudo killall VDCAssistant`

In order to resolve another similar issue with the built-in Microphone:

- Open `Terminal.app`; and
- Run: `sudo killall coreaudio`

Answer (score 0):

Running disk utility and reinstalling the O/S are probably not the best first things to do.**Except** you can run disk utility (/Applications/Utilities) and select your Mac HD and click on repair permissions. That **will** work while you are logged on and started from your main startup volume. Permissions can get munged and doing this is usually quick, easy and a decent first step.

Logs can all be found by running the console.app in /Applications/Utilities. Being a linux guy you are probably well on your way once you've found the logs.